# Managing content inside a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an app that consists of 3 fragments as tabs based upon an initial activity.

The middle tab has a button to save a date. This is just a date picker that adds the selected date to local preferences.

After setting this date, when I slide to the left fragment tab I want to see that date.

What do I need to change / consider in terms of fragment life-cycle or anything else so that when I update this value in the middle fragment tab, I can get, use and display the data on the leftmost fragment tab immediately.

Currently it only works when I close the app. Re-creating the fragment does not seem to get an updated date value. I've tried re-getting the data in onCreate, onStart, onResume, instantiateItem etc.

The tabs code is based off of this simple, official Google example project: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html

I've not included any code yet as the concept can be easily replicated / understood from the example project.

```
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), then you can create a [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) in your left fragment that listens for the date changing and updates its view appropriately.

Comment: The left fragments listener does not appear to hear changes made when the changes are made in the middle fragment.

Comment: @Twentyonehundred - and why is that? Is the change listener getting unregistered (add logging/breakpoints on your register/unregister calls) or is `onSharedPreferenceChanged` not being called? Make sure you are registering your listener with the same type of call to `getSharedPreferences`.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've moved a simple listener around, currently I have "sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener" with an onSharedPreferenceChanged and a log inside onResume, and the same with unregisterOnShared... on pause.